# Raspberry pi: performance of Python VS C# with mono

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi, runtime, benchmarking

I'd like to start programming Raspberry Pi. What I wish to program needs to run fast (1 millisecond is the tolerable lag). I have C# knowledge but no Python knowledge.

Do you think C# code would run fast enough? -I am referring to installing Linux and using mono, not to installing Windows IoT.
If you know of any C# VS Python performance benchmark results on Raspberry Pi, those would be very appreciated.

More details on what my code should do:

- Control another piece of hardware through a serial port (USB)
- Display a GUI window to a local user
- Interact with the user through attached keyboard, mouse and computer screen
- Display a slider control (range control) as part of the GUI
- As the user is using the mouse to move the slider control, my code should immediately do some light processing and then output the result as a command to the other piece of hardware.

Thank you very much for your time.